# Finding centroids without K-means

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, sampling, error, k-means

**The Data:**
Currently I have a simple distribution that looks like the histogram below. Every point is an integer between 0 and 16 and I have 350MB of these samples.

**The Problem:**
I want to identify 8 centroids besides 0 that minimize sampling error. I have used K-Means however I believe it must be extremely inefficient.

**The Question:**
I am no good at stats, but there must be a way to solve this solution simply using the counts of the values [0:16]. Is there a technique to calculate the centroids in this way ?

[image: sample histogram]

Comment: use quantile to find

Comment: Will quantile minimize mean/sum squared error the same way k-means does ?